# Efficient way to index text files

Tags: software-rec, tags

I have a series of text files I'm downloading from a Yahoo Group and I'd like to tag them and index them. What program will help me do this?

Comment: You mean something like a desktop search program?

Comment: Actually, I'd probably want to make it web accessible...

Comment: It might be useful to know the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

- [Omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html), which is a preconfigured indexer based upon the [Xapian search engine](http://xapian.org/).
- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is a full text search server, based [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).
- [Nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Features), which is a search engine, also based upon [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Funcionality for indexing text files is built into Windows Vista/7 and available for XP by downloading either Google Desktop Search or Window's Desktop Search.

Of course, if you're interested in only indexing and tagging these specific files, I would recommend [Microsoft Office OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/), it is web accesible and offers a lot of useful note-taking features.

> With Microsoft OneNote 2010 you can collect and organize everything you need—notes, photos, videos, and web links— for any project you are working on. OneNote keeps the information you need at your fingertips and, with powerful search capabilities, you can easily find exactly what you are looking for. Toss those paper-based notebooks in the recycling bin—you’ve got a digital notebook now!, part of the Microsoft Office suite.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) helpful for achieving your task:

> Evernote makes it easy to remember things big and small from your notable life using your computer, phone, and the web.
>
> **1. Capture everything.**
>
> Chances are, if you can see it or think of it, Evernote can help you remember it. Type a text note. Clip a web page. Snap a photo. Grab a screenshot. Evernote will keep it all safe.
>
> **2. Organize it. (Or let us do it.)**
>
> Everything you capture is automatically processed, indexed, and made searchable. If you like, you can add tags or organize notes into different notebooks.
>
> **3. Find anything fast.**
>
> Search for notes by keywords, titles, and tags. Evernote magically makes printed and handwritten text inside your images searchable, too.